# How to inform OAuth2 API clients about missing credentials?

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, vert.x

I build a REST API using Vert.x and would like to add OAuth2 authentication.

In my current setup unauthenticated requests will automatically be redirected to the OAuth2 server (keycloak) login page. This seems wrong when dealing with a REST API. Instead I would expect my REST API server to return a 401 and thus let the client deal with the process of getting the access token.

Is there a best practice for this use case? How should unauthenticated requests to protected resources be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a access token is missing you should return an HTTP 400. If the token is invalid it would have to be HTTP 401 as shown in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-3.1:

> 3.1.  Error Codes
>
> When a request fails, the resource server responds using the
> appropriate HTTP status code (typically, 400, 401, 403, or 405) and
> includes one of the following error codes in the response:
>
> invalid_request
>
> ```
>      The request is missing a required parameter, includes an
>      unsupported parameter or parameter value, repeats the same
>      parameter, uses more than one method for including an access
>      token, or is otherwise malformed.  The resource server SHOULD
>      respond with the HTTP 400 (Bad Request) status code.
> ```
>
> invalid_token
>
> ```
>      The access token provided is expired, revoked, malformed, or
>      invalid for other reasons.  The resource SHOULD respond with
>      the HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) status code.  The client MAY
>      request a new access token and retry the protected resource
>      request.
> ```
>
> insufficient_scope
>
> ```
>      The request requires higher privileges than provided by the
>      access token.  The resource server SHOULD respond with the HTTP
>      403 (Forbidden) status code and MAY include the "scope"
>      attribute with the scope necessary to access the protected
>      resource.
> ```
>
> If the request lacks any authentication information (e.g., the
> client    was unaware that authentication is necessary or attempted
> using an    unsupported authentication method), the resource server
> SHOULD NOT    include an error code or other error information.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>  HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="example"
> ```